# Using dplyr expand to obtain combination of variables present in data?

Tags: r, dplyr

New to R and trying to use dplyr's expand & nesting functions to obtain a 'complete' subset of my data. I have an ID variable, and a year variable, and I'd like to work only with data where there is a year for each ID within a given range. With the below example, I'd like the function to return the data set with A and C, but not B, since there is an implicit missing value for 2020.

When I try to do this, I receive a tibble error that the columns do not have compatible sizes. Below is my example and the error I receive. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I've tried a few approaches and been unable to fix the problem.

```
example <- tibble(
  ID = c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'),
  YEAR = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2018,2019,2020)
)


full_set <- example %>%
  tidyr::expand(nesting(ID, YEAR = 2018:2020))

Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes. * Size 8: Existing data. * Size 3: Column `YEAR`. i Only values of size one are recycled.
```

Comment: `full_set <- example %>% filter(YEAR %in% 2018:2020)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `complete()` from `tidyr` to generate all combinations of `ID` and `YEAR`. The `flag` is auxiliary to filter out those `ID` with missing `YEAR`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example %>%
  mutate(flag = TRUE) %>%
  complete(ID, YEAR) %>%
  filter(!ID %in% ID[is.na(flag)]) %>%
  select(-flag)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   ID     YEAR
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 A      2018
# 2 A      2019
# 3 A      2020
# 4 C      2018
# 5 C      2019
# 6 C      2020
```

Comment: This is a more concise version of what I also posted. Thank you! Will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
example %>% mutate(min=min(YEAR),max=max(YEAR)) %>%
  filter(ID!='C') %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(ID = .$ID, year = seq(.$min, .$max, by = 1)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
# Rowwise: 
   ID     year
   <fct> <dbl>
 1 A      2018
 2 A      2019
 3 A      2020
 4 A      2018
 5 A      2019
 6 A      2020
 7 A      2018
 8 A      2019
 9 A      2020
10 B      2018
11 B      2019
12 B      2020
13 B      2018
14 B      2019
15 B      2020
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance. I was able to find a solution close to what I was looking for, but not exactly the most concise. I decided to post here for posterity and am always open to suggestions to cleaning code.

```
in_data <- example %>%
  tidyr::expand(nesting(ID, YEAR))

all <- example %>%
  tidyr::expand(ID,YEAR)

missing <- all %>%
  anti_join(in_data)

complete <- example %>%
  filter(!ID %in% unique(missing$ID))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  ID     YEAR
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A      2018
2 A      2019
3 A      2020
4 C      2018
5 C      2019
6 C      2020
```